# Spark DynamoDB Connectivity Issue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

**Requirement:** Read data from DynamoDB(not local but on AWS) via Spark using Scala from my local machine.

**Understanding:** Data can be read using the emr-hadoop-dynamodb.jar when we are using an EMR cluster

**Question**:

1. Can we read data from DynamoDB(on cloud and not local) using the emr-dynamodb-hadoop.jar?
2. EMR cluster is not to be used. I directly want to access dynamodb from spark using scala code on my local machine

*build.sbt*

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
scalacOptions := Seq("-target:jvm-1.8")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "software.amazon.awssdk" % "dynamodb" % "2.15.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.1",
  "com.amazon.emr" % "emr-dynamodb-hadoop" % "4.2.0",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5"
)

dependencyOverrides ++= {
  Seq(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.6.7.1",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.7",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.7"
  )
}
```

*readDataFromDDB.scala*

```
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object readDataFromDDB {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var sc: SparkContext = null
    try {
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DynamoDBApplication").setMaster("local")
      sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val jobConf = getDynamoDbJobConf(sc, "Music", "TableNameForWrite")
      val tableData = sc.hadoopRDD(jobConf, classOf[DynamoDBInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[DynamoDBItemWritable])
      println(tableData.count())

    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        println(e.getStackTrace)
      }
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
    }
  }

  private def getDynamoDbJobConf(sc: JavaSparkContext, tableNameForRead: String, tableNameForWrite: String) = {
    val jobConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    jobConf.set("dynamodb.servicename", "dynamodb")
    jobConf.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", tableNameForRead)
    jobConf.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", tableNameForWrite)
    jobConf.set("dynamodb.awsAccessKeyId", "*****************")
    jobConf.set("dynamodb.awsSecretAccessKey", "*********************")
    jobConf.set("dynamodb.endpoint", "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
    jobConf.set("dynamodb.regionid", "us-east-1")
    jobConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")
    jobConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")
    jobConf
  }
}
```

**ERROR**

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup table Music in DynamoDB.
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient.describeTable(DynamoDBClient.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.ReadIopsCalculator.getThroughput(ReadIopsCalculator.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.ReadIopsCalculator.calculateTargetIops(ReadIopsCalculator.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.initReadManager(AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.(AbstractDynamoDBRecordReader.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DefaultDynamoDBRecordReader.(DefaultDynamoDBRecordReader.java:24)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat.getRecordReader(DynamoDBInputFormat.java:32)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.liftedTree1$1(HadoopRDD.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:403)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:409)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Socket not created by this factory
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.handleException(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.runWithRetry(DynamoDBFibonacciRetryer.java:83)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBClient.describeTable(DynamoDBClient.java:105)
... 20 more

*Links already reviewed*

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-your-data-on-amazon-dynamodb-with-apache-spark/

[read/write dynamo db from apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797324/read-write-dynamo-db-from-apache-spark/46866511)

[Spark 2.2.0 - How to write/read DataFrame to DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722648/spark-2-2-0-how-to-write-read-dataframe-to-dynamodb)

https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector

Answer (score 1):

This was solved when the following dependency version were updated

```
"software.amazon.awssdk" % "dynamodb" % "2.15.31",
"com.amazon.emr" % "emr-dynamodb-hadoop" % "4.14.0"
```